# rename images using terminal script in linux

Tags: terminal, file-rename

In my `/home/myself/Pictures/travels` folder on the `Fedora 17` linux I have files `IMG_2516.JPG`, `IMG_2519.JPG`, `IMG_2520.JPG`, `IMG_2525.JPG`, `IMG_2528.JPG`.

I would like to rename them one by one from left to right such that `IMG_2516.JPG` becomes `01.JPG`, `IMG_2519.JPG` - `02.JPG`, `IMG_2520.JPG` - `03.JPG`, `IMG_2525.JPG` - `04.JPG`, `IMG_2528.JPG` - `05.JPG`.

Notice that neighbouring numbers can be close (as 2519 and 2520) and distant (2516 and 2519), but always increase.

How can I write a terminal script to substitute the routine. These numbers are given for example, there many more files and at the moment I can only manually rename them (very time-consuming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images all have the same number of digits:

```
I=1
for F in IMG_*.JPG; do
    mv "$F" IMG_$(printf "%02d" $I).JPG
    I=$(( I + 1 ))
done
```

Otherwise,

```
LIST=$(mktemp)
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.jpg" > $LIST
sort -n -o $LIST $LIST
I=1
cat $LIST | while read F; do
    mv "$F" IMG_$(printf "%02d" $I).JPG
    I=$(( I + 1 ))
done
rm "$LIST"
```

The first one means: For each image, move it to IMG_0I.JPG, increase I by 1.

The second one means:

- make a temporary file
- find all of the JPG files in the directory (and not subdirectories, case-insensitive), 
  save one per line in the temporary file.
- sort them by their numerical ordering (-n) and write back to the temporary file (-o)
- send the contents of the file to the following:

-- while there is a next line,

-- -- store it in F

-- -- move the file with that name to I, where I is represented with two digits and padded with leading zeros, prefixed with IMG_ and postfixed with .JPG

-- -- increase I

Comment: You mean `IMG_$(printf "%02d" $I).JPG;` `I=$(( I + 1 )).`

Comment: NP :-) Sorry about the bug.